# When I try to install any package through the command line, I get an error. Can anyone help me on this?

Tags: 14.04

[The Error Message is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RiGP.png)

```
jishnu@chandralayam:~$ sudo apt install r-base-core
sudo: unable to resolve host chandralayam
[sudo] password for jishnu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package r-base-core
jishnu@chandralayam:~$
```

Comment: You might have changed the hostname and that's why you get the unable to resolve host error.  Type cat /etc/hosts and provide output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `r-base-core` package is in the "universe" repository. You may need to enable "universe" manually before you can install that package.

To enable the "universe" repository on Ubuntu 14.04, run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe"
```

Then refresh your package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and now you should be able to install the r-base-core package:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core
```

Please let me know if this was helpful!